# getting customer group using Grid control

Tags: sales-order

I would like to get the customer group in `Sales > Order` grid. I'm using the [gridcontrol](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/GridControl) module for this.

I used below XML tag to get customer group but after that I do not see any order. I think my join query is wrong:

```
<join table="customer/customer_group" condition="main_table.customer_id ={{table}}.customer_group_id" field="customer_group_code"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is, as you're joining a customer id with a customer **group** id. The main_table is sales_flat_order. It has a customer_group_id field, which can be NULL.

Comment: how to fix it.. i wan to get customer group code her